# `dplyr` not working with `MASS` package in `r`

Tags: r, dplyr

I am encountering a strange problem in using packages `MASS` and `dplyr` together in `R` using `RStudio`. The following code

```
library(dplyr)
select(iris, starts_with("Petal"))
```

works and gives me the right output. But if I try to load `MASS` package and use the same code

```
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)
select(iris, starts_with("Petal"))
```

I get an error

```
select(iris, starts_with("Petal"))
Error in select(iris, starts_with("Petal")) : 
  unused argument (starts_with("Petal"))
```

Is there a known issue with using `dplyr` with `MASS` in `RStudio`. I am loading `dplyr` after `MASS` so as not to mask the `select` from `dplyr`. I have un-installed and re-installed my `RStudio` also, but the error persists.

I am using R Version `3.2.2`, `MASS` version - `7.3-45` and `dplyr` version `0.5.0`

Any help would be highly appreciated!

sn248

Comment: For future reference, RStudio != R. RStudio is "just" an IDE, it doesn't really impact what's going on with your R code. So re-installing RStudio (and the RStudio tag) were unnecessary here.

Comment: Thanks, as I was typing this question - a similar question popped up in Stackoverflow which recommended un/re-installing the IDE. So, I tried it and mentioned that I have already tried that step.

Comment: In the chunk that gives you the error... shouldn't you load dplyr before MASS to get that error?

Comment: That was my question, even though I was loading `dplyr` after `MASS`, I was getting an error, don't know why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both packages have a `select` function.

Use `dplyr::select()` or `MASS::select()` as needed to prevent errors.

Another popular conflict is the `dplyr::filter` vs `signal::filter`.

If you don't want to type the package name every time you can type once `dselect <- dplyr::select` and then use `dselect` all the time instead.

Comment: Today's episode of "tidyverse considered harmful" as it stomps over base R and recommended packages.

Comment: thanks, somehow the `select` now works, but your solution is helpful and should work every time

Comment: If I had created a general purpose package (such as dplyr) and I knew about signal and MASS I would have avoided the conflict, choosing something like `filter_rows` and `filter_columns` instead of `filter` and `select`. But I would not say that there is a daily episode of "tidyverse considered harmful" because of this... the tidyverse is not perfect but its benefits outweight the downsides from my humble point of view...

Comment: @SN248 I think it "works" now because the code you posted had the library calls in the wrong order and now you're running the code in the order that you posted here.