# Dunnett's test that is compatible with the tidyverse in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I see when I run `library(multcomp)` (see [this example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83116/dunnetts-test-in-r-returning-different-values-each-time)), it complains (among other things):

```
Attaching package: ‘MASS’

The following object is masked from ‘package:dplyr’:

    select
```

Masking select is going to be awkward.

I suppose I can use multcomp without putting it into the namespace with `library`.

**EDIT**: What is the easiest way to run Dunnett's test that works well with the tidyverse?

(Old question: Is there another package that offers Dunnett's test that is more compatible with the tidyverse?)

Comment: If you have a preference for masking, use `library(confliced);conflict_prefer("select", winner = "dplyr", quiet = FALSE)`

Comment: Have you tried loading dplyr/tidyverse *after* multcomp? Then `dplyr::select()` will mask `MASS::select()`, which sounds like it would be preferable to you. That's the advice given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24202391/8386140 . You could also do `select <- dplyr::select` a la https://stackoverflow.com/a/43051797/8386140  (Apparently conflicts with `dplyr` are a pretty common problem)

Comment: Can you please rephrase this to make it about the problem you're trying to solve (`multcomp` loads `MASS` which masks `dplyr::select`) rather than "is there a package that ..."? (which is off-topic for StackOverflow) ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker Thanks for your feedback. Tried rephrasing. The problem I'm trying to solve is not "multcomp loads MASS..". That is a symptom. I am trying to run Dunnett's test smoothly with tidyverse.